# Function argument as key to array

Tags: jquery, arrays, associative-array

I need find a value in associative array by it key. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
$.fn.array_search = function(what, where, array_key){

    for (var key in where) {
        if (where[key].array_key == what) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: when you say associative array you mean some thing like `var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46};`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, like `var persons = {{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46}, {firstName:"Tom", lastName:"Dav", age:25}, ...}` and find by firstName, for example

Comment: just added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)  when working with objects and trying to find a key, the `hasOwnProperty()` method returns a `boolean` indicating whether the `object` has the specified `property` as own `(not inherited)` property. This method can be used to determine whether an `object` has the specified property as a direct property of that object unlike the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype chain.

Then you can use [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype), to define your `prototype` for your array. The `Array.prototype` property represents the `prototype` for the Array constructor and allows you to add new properties and methods to all `Array` objects.

I updated your function as follows, hope it helps.

```js
var arrayC = [{
    name: "omer",
    age: 16,
    city: "pakistan"
  },
  {
    name: "ali",
    age: 26,
    city: "pakistan"
  }
];


// If JavaScript doesn't provide a assoc_search() method natively,
if (!Array.prototype.assoc_search) {

  // returns after finding the first match for the given key => value pair and return the value
  Array.prototype.assoc_search = function(what, array_key) {

    let where = this;

    for (var key in where) {
      if (where[key].hasOwnProperty(array_key) && where[key][array_key] == what) {
        return where[key][array_key];
      }
    }
    return false;

  };
}

var result = arrayC.assoc_search("omer", "name");
(result) ? console.log('found ' + result): console.log('not found ');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```